# Tape Reduction when T is not time constructible

Tags: complexity-theory

[Arora and Barak](https://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/book.pdf) showed in their book that we can simulate a $O(T(n))$ time-bounded $k$-tape Turing machine with a $O(T(n)\log{T(n)})$ time-bounded $2$-tape oblivious Turing machine. But it seems that they assume that $T(n)$ is time constructible. What if $T(n)$ is not time constructible? Can we still do this simulation efficiently?